# How to post multiple arrays from java using json

Tags: java, android, json

I have 3 arrays. say, X is a string array having 3 values {X1,X2,X3}. Y is an integer array having 3 values {Y1,Y2,Y3}. Z is list having 3 values {Z1,Z2,Z3}. Can some tell me how to post these using json and then parse using php to retrieve them into variables say M,N,O. But it is posting a reference id when I do this for each variable(X,Y,Z). I am trying to post using

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("X", X.tostring());
json.put("Y", Y.tostring());
json.put("Z", Z.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform X, Y and Z into JSON arrays:

```
json.put("X", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(X)));
```

Comment: {"X":["[I@40557df8"],"Y":["358920045318901"],"Z":["[0.0]"]}.
Can you help me find why it is returning me a reference Id for X. X is an int[]

Comment: Because Arrays.asList() transforms an array of objects into a List. For an array of primitives, you'll need to create an empty JSONArray, and loop through the primitive array to add every int to the JSONArray.